# Run Program Before Login Screen Appears

Tags: windows, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I start a program even before Windows starts itself?](https://superuser.com/questions/297525/how-can-i-start-a-program-even-before-windows-starts-itself)

I want Windows to run a command line program before it even loads the login (or Welcome) screen. If you've ever seen this screen, you know what I mean:
[image]

I want this program to be executed **exactly** at the above stage/screen (before any driver is loaded). The reason and purpose are too complicated to explain here. But is this possible?

Comment: This screen actually appears AFTER (at least some) drivers have loaded, or else Windows wouldn't be able to recognize the drive's file system to run the disk check.

Comment: What version of XP are you running? Pro or Home?

Comment: @techie007: Burdges is correct. Driver is not loaded yet at that stage. Chkdsk must be able to read the C: volume in RAW mode. This is only possible if there's no file in it is open. That's why chkdsk can't run with the /r switch on drive C: in Win32 environment.

Comment: @Larssend - You can't run /F or /R on a system drive while windows is (fully) running due to locked/in-use system files (page file, etc.). (At least) the Kernel drivers need to be loaded, or else Windows couldn't use the hardware, let alone the file system (RAW or otherwise).  Think of a RAID that XP doesn't have native support for, how are you going use or check a drive that Windows can't see because you didn't give it the F6 driver? :)

Comment: @KCotreau: I have two computers: one is running Pro and the other Home. I'd like to do this on both. Maybe you or anyone else can figure out a creative way of some sort.

Comment: @techie007: Yes, you're just providing detail to my answer.

Comment: Please stop arguing in the comments. It's distracting. Sorry and thank you.

Comment: @techie007 Although he commented to my answer that he was really trying to run a different program, you guys might be interested in my solution to running chkdsk every reboot.

Comment: @Burdges - I'm not arguing, I've stated my case, (at least some) drivers _are_ loaded at the point in which you are interested (at least at the point where chkdsk could run, as illustrated). Please just take it as the intended cautionary warning, as it contradicts ideas included in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can *not* run just any program at that stage. Only applications that use the 'native' NT API (provided by NTDLL.dll) can be run before Win32 subsystem is loaded.

To check if a program can be run at that particular stage, do the following:

1. Run Registry Editor (`regedit.exe`).
2. Navigate to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager` and locate a multi-string (*REG_MULTI_SZ*) entry called `BootExecute`.
3. Double click the entry and Add the name of the executable you want to test excluding path. The executable must be located in `%windir%\system32`.
4. Reboot.

If the program runs in the Native NT environment, you win. Otherwise, there's nothing you can do about it unless you have access to the program's source code.

Read [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897447) Technet Article for more information about Native NT application.

Comment: Yup, have fun with that one! It sure isnt going to be a cake walk to test.